# Jboss Studio EL validation fails on jsf bean with injected spring bean

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jboss, el

When in a managed bean i inject a spring bean like this:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{lijstService}")
private LijstService lijstService;
```

I get following warning:

"lijstService" cannot be resolved

When using other JSF beans it works. I guess this is the validation of Jboss which fails to lookup the spring bean... How do i solve this or could this be a bug?

Comment: JBoss Tools is designed for Java EE, not for its competitor Spring. Try a Spring aware plugin instead if you absolutely need to go the Spring path instead of the Java EE path.

Comment: Is it just a problem in the IDE or also runtime?

Comment: @BalusC: True, however they do support non-EE frameworks sometimes... Tomcat is for instance supported in their arquillian framework (but limited yes...) I hoped in this case, since Spring is widely used, they would offer some EL support for it. If you are sure it is not a bug, then you can put it as an answer. Also, you mentioned a Spring aware plugin, do you know a good one? BTW, I'm using both JSF and Spring.

Comment: @Kukeltje: Only IDE, but since we forked another project which contains lots of warnings which we would like to be fixed, with this one it is becoming a lot :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Spring, so I can't tell if there's any decent Eclipse plugin for that. They do appear to have something like "Spring Tools Suite" plugin for Eclipse which you could theoretically use instead of JBoss Studio. But perhaps you'd better replace JSF managed beans by Spring managed beans altogether so you can just use @Autowired and friends. You're here basically mixing technologies from different vendors instead of sticking to one and same vendor (Java EE vs Spring). You can't expect an IDE plugin targeted at one vendor to take into account the other vendor.

Comment: @BalusC: I totally agree. But I'm a JSF lover and it is a very powerful framework. We are for the moment forced to use tomcat (unfortunately :( ) and therefore Spring (openEJB or other stuff like this simply not mature enough yet). Would you give up JSF for using Spring and its friends, just not to mix technologies which otherwise work very well together lately?

Comment: I didn't said to give up JSF. Just to replace JSF bean management facility by Spring bean management facility. You can keep using JSF views. If you'd need to give up JSF altogether, the only choice you have in Spring is Spring MVC and this has a completely different ideology, requiring much more boilerplate code after all.

Comment: Yes, Spring (or Spring MVC) stands for boilerplate, I also strongly prefer to avoid it, but current project doesn't allow it... I want absolutely to use JSF. Well, honestly, your proposal confuses me a bit, because I didn't know it was possible. I have tried to Springify my managed beans, and indeed, it works the same way. And... my warning disappears. :) Thanks for the suggestion, it solves my issue so will you add this as answer?